# alsamixerの設定について

Tags: linux

はじめましてALSA初心者です。

alsamixerを起動した後、F6キーで選択できる「Select sound card」の情報は、どこを参照しているのでしょうか？

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [HDMI           ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel HDMI
                      HDA Intel HDMI at 0xf7d34000 irq 53
 1 [PCH            ]: HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH
                      HDA Intel PCH at 0xf7d30000 irq 54
```

のようにsound cardは2種類あるように認識しているみたいなのですが、alsamixerではdefaultしか選択できません。

皆様のご意見をよろしくお願いします。

Comment: aplay -l の挙動がrootと通常ユーザーで異なることが判りました。rootではデバイスが確認できますが、通常ユーザーではサウンドカードが見つかりません。

$ aplay -l
aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...

Answer (score 2):

正常な環境では ls -al /dev/snd でサウンド関連のデバイスファイルに "+" がついていて ACL が付加されていることを確認。

getfacl /dev/snd/seq で確認するとログインしているユーザーのACLが付加されていることが確認でき、

sudo setfacl -m u:username:rw /dev/snd/*

でパーミッションを変更することで回避できることが確認できました。